# Calculate $ \biggr\lfloor \frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}} + \frac{1}{5^{\frac{1}{3}}} + ... + \frac{1}{1000000^{\frac{1}{3}}} \biggr\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Calculate $ \biggr\lfloor  \frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}  +   \frac{1}{5^{\frac{1}{3}}}  +   \frac{1}{6^{\frac{1}{3}}}  + ... +   \frac{1}{1000000^{\frac{1}{3}}} \biggr\rfloor$

I am just clueless. I just have some random thoughts. I can find the sum of this series and then put in the value $1000000$ and then find the floor of that. To do this, I would have to telescope this series which seems impossible to me. But is there any other way to directly find the floor without finding the general sum?

I am very new to calculus, so please provide hints and answers that dio not involve calculus.

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin?

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ is approximately constant on short intervals of $[3,+\infty)$, the inner sum is expected to be pretty close to... which integral?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What is it sir?

Comment: @ami_ba I see now the editing, really you are requested to solve without calculus?

Comment: I will be grateful to anyone who provides me any hint for a completely pre calculus solution

Comment: @ami_ba Sorry but I really have not idea how to proceed by a precalcus solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$(x^a)' = ax^{a-1}$,
$a\int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx
=(n+1)^a-n^a
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
v^a-u^a
&=\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}((n+1)^a-n^a)\\
&=\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}a\int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx\\
\end{array}
$

If $a > 1$,
since $x^{a-1}$
is increasing,
$n^{a-1} 
\lt \int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx
\lt (n+1)^{a-1}
$.

If $a < 1$,
since $x^{a-1}$
is decreasing,
$n^{a-1} 
\gt \int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx
\gt (n+1)^{a-1}
$.

In this case,
$a-1 = -1/3 < 0$.
Therefore
$v^a-u^a
=\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}a\int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx
\lt \sum_{n=u}^{v-1}an^{a-1}
$
so
$\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}n^{a-1}
\gt \frac1{a}(v^a-u^a)
$.

Similarly,
$v^a-u^a
=\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}a\int_n^{n+1} x^{a-1}dx
\gt \sum_{n=u}^{v-1}a(n+1)^{a-1}
= a\sum_{n=u+1}^{v}n^{a-1}
= a\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}n^{a-1}-a(u^{a-1}-v^{a-1})
$
so
$\sum_{n=u}^{v-1}n^{a-1}
\lt \frac1{a}((v-1)^a-u^a)+(u^{a-1}-v^{a-1})
$.

The reverse inequalities hold
if $a > 1$.

In this case,
$a-1=-1/3,
a = 2/3,
v=10^6+1,
u=4$,
so,
if
$s = \sum_{n=u}^{v-1}n^{a-1}$,
then
$s 
\gt \frac1{2/3}((10^6)^{2/3}-4^{2/3})
\gt \frac32(10^4-2.519...)
\approx 14996.220
$
and
$s 
\lt \frac1{2/3}((10^6)^{2/3}-4^{2/3})+(4^{-1/3}-(10^6)^{-1/3})
\approx 14996.220+0.619
= 14996.839
$

so
$\lfloor s \rfloor
=14996
$.

If the lower and upper bounds
surrounded an integer,
I would manually compute
the first few terms
until the bounds
for the remaining terms
are close enough
that the floor is determined.

Answer (score 5):

Following tha suggesion given by Jack D'Aurizio in the comments, by integral bounding we have that

$$14996.23\approx\int_4^{1\,000\,001}\frac1{x^{1/3}}dx\le\sum_{k=4}^{1\,000\,000} \frac1{k^{1/3}}\le\int_4^{1\,000\,001}\frac1{(x-1)^{1/3}}dx\approx14996.88$$